# OpenCV is not graying an image with cv2.cvtColor when displayed with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, image-processing, grayscale

I tried to gray an image but it does not work properly like it should. It just applied a kind of filter as you can see by using cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY function. Kindly someone help me to get over with this issue.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're using **matplotlib** to show your grayscale image. Matplotlib applies a **colormap**. By default that's a colorful one.

Add `cmap="gray"` in your `imshow` call: `plt.imshow(img_gray, cmap="gray")`

Comment: thanks, it worked, but i am curious that in every tutorial they don't use "cmap" parameter and everything works fine. Is this because any version issue?

Comment: no. in those tutorials they use _color images_, which matplotlib will show as-is.